# Access row data via client side API of GridView

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have a DevExpress GridView in my Asp.NET MVC 4 application and want to access row data on the client side via JavaScript. At the moment I am doing the following:

Specify which values should be transmitted to js function ChangeDetailsTab:

```
function OnGridFocusedRowChanged(s, e) {
        s.GetRowValues(s.GetFocusedRowIndex(),
            'MOL_REGID;BATCH_NAME;MOL_NAME;MOL_ENTERED_BY;', ChangeDetailsTab);
}
```

Access values from array received by ChangeDetailsTab:

```
function ChangeDetailsTab(rowData) {

    var molRegId= rowData[0];
    var batchName= rowData[1];
    var molName= rowData[2];
    var molEnteredBy= rowData[3];
}
```

This approach makes it quite bad to access a large number of values or add/remove values later because the column names have to be specified in one large string (see example 1 line 3).

Has anyone a better solution for this problem?

Comment: Why don't you contact DX guys directly?

Comment: Thought to give you guys here a try over the weekend ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The client-side **GetRowValues** is specially designed for this purpose.

I believe it is the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

this is best way,Of course a any way for this,you can called in C# Code,in CustomCallback you can run it,in client side on the javascript you can perform,such
`ASPxGridView1.PerformCallback()`(ASPxGridView1 has a event that named `CustomCallback`)with this you without reload page can get value of C# code
in C# Code :

```
ASPxGridView1.GetRowValues(ASPxGridView1.FocusedRowIndex,"column1","column2",....)
```

of course you remember that should called this event from java script in client-side

Answer (score 0):

**Which method is faster?** I'm loading multiple values but it seems slow for some reason.

I'm doing the setup similar to what you have but I have about 25 - 30 values being loaded.

```
function insuranceselectionchange() {
   insuranceselection.GetRowValues(insuranceselection.GetFocusedRowIndex(), 'CarrierName;CarrierAddress;CarrierAddress2')
}

function SetInsuranceValues(values) {
   CarrierName.SetText(values[0]);
   CarrierAddress.SetText(values[1]);
   CarrierAddress2.SetText(values[2]);
}
```